# Integrate rcov with Sublime Text 2 Ruby Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, sublimetext2, rcov

Is there a way to integrate rcov with the Sublime Text 2 Ruby Tests package?

I'm working on Windows by the way. Running my rspec tests works great in Sublime Text, but I'd like this rcov to be integrated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.[RCov](https://github.com/relevance/rcov) does not work on Ruby 1.9.x. For coverage on Ruby 1.9 look at [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov).
2.**For reference：** [SublimePythonCoverage](https://github.com/davisagli/SublimePythonCoverage) is a plugin for Sublime Text 2 that can highlight lines of Python lacking test coverage, based on the output of Ned Batchelder's [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/).